# Wavefunction Collapse of a Degenerate System with a Finite Range Measurement

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction-collapse

A particle, at time $t=T$, has the following wavefunction:

$\left| \psi  \right> =\frac { 1 }{ \sqrt { 4 }  } \left( \left| A \right> \left| - \right> +\left| B \right> \left| + \right> +\left| C \right> \left| - \right> +\left| D \right> \left| + \right>  \right) $

where $A$,$B$,$C$,$D$ are the (normalised) position wavefunctions and $+$,$-$ are the spin wavefunctions.  The energy of the particle depends on its position, but not its spin.  $A$ has the lowest energy (ground state), $B$ and $C$ have the same energy, $D$ has the highest energy.

Imagine we make a measurement at time $t=T$.  We only measure its energy, but not its spin.  Also, we don't measure the particle's exact energy, instead we check whether its energy is equal to its ground state $A$.  The result is that the particle is not in its ground state.  What is the wavefunction of the particle after the measurement?

In essence, I would like to understand what does a wavefunction collapse into, when:

- the measurement is not exact but it covers a range of eigenstates (such as a measurement that determines whether the energy is within a certain range, rather than a measurement that determines the exact energy).
- the measurement does not measure other properties (such as only measuring the particle's position but not measuring its spin)
- some states are degenerate (such as state $B$ and state $C$ having the same energy)

Note that I'm not talking about the uncertainty of our apparatus here; I'm considering the situation where our measurements are perfect and we simply choose not to measure everything.

Comment: @Jakob Rather than determining the particle's exact energy, I make a measurement that determines if: it has an energy equal to or less than the ground state OR it has an energy greater than the ground state.

Comment: @Jakob I'm just trying to invent an example to illustrate my point of a measurement that covers a range rather than being exact.  Maybe take this other example: I measure the particle's position to be between x=a and x=b, rather than measuring its exact location.

Comment: Does [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/92869/the-quantum-state-just-after-a-position-measurement/92894#92894) help?